# Cocos2D v1.0.1 on iPad Retina - Black Screen

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have developed an app using Cocos2D-iPhone version 1.0.1. When I load the app in the iPad Retina simulator or on an actual device, the screen is black. I read that iPad Retina support begins with 0.13.0-beta. So, I guess that means that it should be working with version 1.0.1. Is there some switch that is needed to enable this for iPad Retina? If it doesn't work on this version, then what version do I need? And if I need to upgrade, is there a documented process for upgrading an xcode project?

Comment: v1.0 has no iPad retina support, v1.1 has. There is no and never was a "0.13.0-beta" version.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - Ok, should I assume that https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/releases/tag/release-1.1 would offer the easiest upgrade path for me? If so, is there a documented procedure to upgrade to this version on an existing Xcode project?

Comment: The upgrade procedure is to delete the old cocos2d code from the project (and by delete I mean delete both in the Xcode project and on disk, so make a backup). Then put the new version in place and re-add the files in Xcode. There will be compilation errors, no docs on those though but look into ccDeprecated.h/.m.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - I found this article of yours (http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/). Is it still a valid upgrade procedure for my case?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - I upgraded to the above mentioned release-1.1 using your procedure in the above mentioned article. Everything compiled, BUT I still have the Black screen when I run the app in the iPad Retina simulator. Did I use the correct version?

Comment: what about Retina device, same issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40603/discussion-between-jeffb6688-and-learncocos2d)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - No, iPhone Retina works fine. Its just a problem with iPad Retina. The launch screen shows, and then it goes black.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - I switched out cocos2d-iphone-release-1.1 with cocos2d-iphone-1.1-RC0. This version does work with iPad Retina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on input from LearnCocos2D, version 1.0.1 does not support iPad Retina and that cocos2d release 1.1 is required. However, the specific release that is required is cocos2d-iphone-1.1-RC0. This requires a few fixes for deprecation issues and interface changes. The upgrade is not too bad if you follow his tutorial found at http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/